# How do I AddRange to a dictionary but filter out empty keys?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

The code in this question generates the following JSON.

The code should exclude empty "Children" keys by virtue of the line `.Where(a => a.Values != null)`, but it doesn't work.

Where can I place that where clause so that JSON doesn't include a bunch of empty "Children" arrays?

Thanks for your help.

```
[{
        "NodeID" : 1,
        "NodeText" : "Country",
        "Children" : [{
                "NodeID" : 3,
                "NodeText" : "President",
                "Children" : []
            }, {
                "NodeID" : 4,
                "NodeText" : "Population",
                "Children" : []
            }, {
                "NodeID" : 5,
                "NodeText" : "State",
                "Children" : [{
                        "NodeID" : 6,
                        "NodeText" : "Governor",
                        "Children" : []
                    }, {
                        "NodeID" : 7,
                        "NodeText" : "Population",
                        "Children" : []
                    }, {
                        "NodeID" : 8,
                        "NodeText" : "County",
                        "Children" : [{
                                "NodeID" : 9,
                                "NodeText" : "Population",
                                "Children" : []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "NodeID" : 2,
        "NodeText" : "Year",
        "Children" : []
    }
]
```

Here's the sample code that generates the JSON above:

```
public class Node
{
    public int? ParentNodeID { get; set; }
    public int NodeID { get; set; }
    public string NodeText { get; set; }

    public Node(int? parentNodeID, int nodeID, string nodeText)
    {
        ParentNodeID = parentNodeID;
        NodeID = nodeID;
        NodeText = nodeText;
    }
}

public List<Dictionary<string, object>> BuildTree(int? parentNodeID = null, List<Node> exampleData = null)
{
    // kickstart the recursion with example data
    if (exampleData == null)
    {
        exampleData = new List<Node>();
        exampleData.Add(new Node(null, 1, "Country"));
        exampleData.Add(new Node(null, 2, "Year"));
        exampleData.Add(new Node(1, 3, "President"));
        exampleData.Add(new Node(1, 4, "Population"));
        exampleData.Add(new Node(1, 5, "State"));
        exampleData.Add(new Node(5, 6, "Governor"));
        exampleData.Add(new Node(5, 7, "Population"));
        exampleData.Add(new Node(5, 8, "County"));
        exampleData.Add(new Node(8, 9, "Population"));
    }

    List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    var nodes = exampleData.Where(a => a.ParentNodeID == parentNodeID).ToList();

    if (nodes != null)
    {
        result.AddRange(nodes
            .Select(a => new Dictionary<string, object> {
                { "NodeID", a.NodeID},
                { "NodeText", a.NodeText },
                { "Children", BuildTree(a.NodeID, exampleData) }
            })
            .Where(a => a.Values != null) // this doesn't have any effect
            .ToList()
        );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: do you want to remove only Children:[] from json, or whole {...} element which contains Children:[]?

Comment: Clarifying question, in the example JSON you gave, what nodes are you expecting to omit? Are they nodes 2, 4, 6, 7, and 9? Also, by definition all nodes at the lowest level are dictionaries with Children:[]... if you remove them, then the parent node becomes a Child:[] as well - how do you want to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are always creating a Dictionary containing a value of "Children", even when there are no children.

The solution is to put that into a condition and just not add the value if there are no children, otherwise you keep adding the Children Key with an empty collection value no matter what.

Here's the code that is working for me to accomplish this: The meat and potatoes is the `Func<T> getNodeDictionary` which is now called inside the recursive statement.

```
    public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> BuildTree(int? parentNodeID = null, List<Node> exampleData = null)
    {
        // kickstart the recursion with example data
        if (exampleData == null)
        {
            exampleData = new List<Node>();
            exampleData.Add(new Node(null, 1, "Country"));
            exampleData.Add(new Node(null, 2, "Year"));
            exampleData.Add(new Node(1, 3, "President"));
            exampleData.Add(new Node(1, 4, "Population"));
            exampleData.Add(new Node(1, 5, "State"));
            exampleData.Add(new Node(5, 6, "Governor"));
            exampleData.Add(new Node(5, 7, "Population"));
            exampleData.Add(new Node(5, 8, "County"));
            exampleData.Add(new Node(8, 9, "Population"));
        }

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        var nodes = exampleData.Where(a => a.ParentNodeID == parentNodeID).ToList();

        if (nodes != null)
        {
            Func<Node, Dictionary<string, object>> getNodeDictionary = n => {
                var children = BuildTree(n.NodeID, exampleData); // still recursive
                var returnDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { // these 2 nodes always get added
                    { "NodeID", n.NodeID},
                    { "NodeText", n.NodeText }
                };

                // This ensures we only add Children if there are actually any children
                if (children.Any())
                {
                    returnDictionary.Add("Children", children);
                }

                return returnDictionary;
            };

            // No need for where clause since we now do not add the empty elements
            result.AddRange(nodes
                .Select(a => getNodeDictionary(a))
                .ToList()
            );
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Wow. No loops, no wasted code, no removing keys. Brilliant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Values` in `.Where(a => a.Values != null)` is always not null for children because you are initalizing it in recursion (`{ "Children", BuildTree(a.NodeID, exampleData) }`). Change Where condition to check for empty children.

You can add method:

```
    private static bool IsNotEmptyTree(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;  //Is empty whatever
        if (value as List<Dictionary<string, object>> != null)
        {
            var dict = (value as List<Dictionary<string, object>>);
            return dict.Count > 0;
        }
        // not empty
        return true;
    }
```

And use it in Where:

```
.Where(a => a.Values.All(IsNotEmptyTree))
```

Comment: Goran, I tried `.Where(a => a.Values.Count > 0)` and `.Where(a => a.Count > 0)`, but neither worked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Aaah I see now, this is not dictionary but list of dictionaries. It is a bit more complicated. I reproduced your issue and updated answer, but this will now return empty object, because in your json all elements have empty children, only if there is some element in some of the children, then it will return non-empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Think of what's happening here. You have:

```
result.AddRange(nodes
    .Select(a => new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "NodeID", a.NodeID},
        { "NodeText", a.NodeText },
        { "Children", BuildTree(a.NodeID, exampleData) }
    })
    .Where(a => a.Values != null) // this doesn't have any effect
    .ToList()
);
```

The `Where` is checking the new item that you created, NOT the node. So it's like saying:

```
var temp1 = nodes.Select(a => new Dictionary<string, object> { ... });
var temp2 = temp1.Where(a => a.Values != null);
result.AddRange(temp2);
```

So `temp1` is a bunch of those anonymous object instances, all of which contain a dictionary that has three key/value pairs in it.

I think what you want is:

```
.Where(a => a["Children"] != null)
```

Assuming, of course, that `BuildTree` returns `null` for an empty list.

Comment: I misunderstood the intent. @DavidKhakin 's answer is the one you want.